# Use Netfilter to write kernel module to modify source IP error, computer crash

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, ubuntu-16.04, netfilter

I want to write a kernel module that uses Netfilter to modify the source ip to "100.100.100.100" whiche packet the Destination IP is "192.68.4.103" and the protocol is TCP.
   I write a .c file but when i install this module ,it will cause the computer crash. How should I rewrite it?
The system is ubuntu16.04 . Here is the code I wrote:

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/netfilter.h>
#include <linux/netfilter_ipv4.h>
#include<linux/inet.h>
#include<net/ip.h>
#include<net/tcp.h>
#include <linux/netdevice.h>
#include <linux/inet.h>
#include <linux/socket.h>
#include <linux/skbuff.h>


MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");  
MODULE_AUTHOR("LINHOS");


#define IF_NAME "eno1"  //Network name which is got by command "ifconfig"
struct nf_hook_ops nfho;

static unsigned int checkIP(
        unsigned int hooknum,  
        struct sk_buff *__skb,
        const struct net_device *in,
        const struct net_device *out,
        int(*okfn)(struct sk_buff *)){
    struct sk_buff *skb; 
    struct net_device *dev; 
    struct iphdr *iph;  
    struct tcphdr *tcph;  
    int tot_len;  
    unsigned int iph_len;  
    int tcph_len;  
    int ret;
    skb = __skb;
    if (skb == NULL)
        return NF_ACCEPT;
    iph = ip_hdr(skb); 
    if (iph == NULL)
        return NF_ACCEPT;
    tot_len = ntohs(iph->tot_len);
    if (iph->daddr =="192.68.4.103") {  //locla ip
        iph_len = ip_hdrlen(skb);
        skb_pull(skb, iph_len);
        skb_reset_transport_header(skb);
        if (iph->protocol == IPPROTO_TCP) {
            tcph = tcp_hdr(skb);
            tcph_len = tcp_hdrlen(skb);
            iph->saddr = in_aton("100.100.100.100"); 
            dev = dev_get_by_name(&init_net, IF_NAME);  
            tcph->check = 0;  
            skb->csum = csum_partial((unsigned char *) tcph,
                                     tot_len - iph_len,
                                     0);

            tcph->check = csum_tcpudp_magic(iph->saddr,
                                            iph->daddr,
                                             ntohs(iph->tot_len) - iph_len,
                                            iph->protocol,
                                            skb->csum);

            iph->check = 0;
            iph->check = ip_fast_csum(iph, iph->ihl); 

            skb->ip_summed = CHECKSUM_NONE;  
            skb->pkt_type = PACKET_HOST; 

            skb->dev = dev;
            skb_push(skb, iph_len);  
            skb_push(skb, ETH_ALEN);  
            ret = dev_queue_xmit(skb);  
            if (ret < 0) {   
                printk(KERN_ERR "dev_queue_xmit() error!\n");
                return NF_DROP;  
            }
            return NF_STOLEN;  
        }
        skb_push(skb, iph_len);
        skb_reset_transport_header(skb);
    }
    return NF_ACCEPT;
}


static int __initfilter_init(void){
    printk("----------------checkIP  is OK!--------------");
    nfho.hook = checkIP;
    nfho.pf = AF_INET;  
    nfho.hooknum = NF_INET_PRE_ROUTING;
    nfho.priority = NF_IP_PRI_FIRST; 
    int ret = nf_register_hook(&nfho);   
    if (ret < 0) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "can't modify skb hook!");
        return ret;
    }
    return 0;
}

static void filter_exit(void) {
    nf_unregister_hook(&nfho);
}

module_init(filter_init);
module_exit(filter_exit);
```

Could anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: From a first look, i see that your init function `filter_init` doesn't exist because of the missing space between `__init` macro and the function's name.

Comment: This is my fault， filter_init is exist, but i wrote it to a __initfilter_init ，it was missing  a Space symbol。today i check this code and find that 'if (iph->daddr =="192.68.4.103")' should be if (iph->daddr ==in_aton("192.68.4.103"))  but it still doesn't work how should i modify it?